# [Flex mobile]About placing many instances of a custom component

Tags: apache-flex, memory, components

Right now , my development of app is in the optimizing stage. I have a problem when adding one of my components: PlayerInfo, which is extended from Group and has some Labels and Images in it,I have to create 60 of this component and put'm all into a HGroup. But in the process of adding them into the hgroup, my app just stops responding for a few seconds,which is not tolerable. Can I achieve this with less memory usage?

I have read [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ff9.html) page and thought if I can do it with any of my components,not only bitmaps.does anyone know how to do that?

here is how I did it:

```
class PlayerInfo extends Group{
 private var name:Label;
 private var age:Label;
 private var photo:Image;
```

}

and in my list class:

```
public function addPlayers(arrPlayer:Array):void{
for(;;){
   var player:PlayerInfo=new PlayerInfo();
   HGroup.addElement(player);
}
```

}

Comment: Better use a `List` with your `PlayerInfo` as custom ItemRenderer instead. It's optimized to only instantiate renderers when they become visible. Your approach will create them all at once. If you don't need List functionality, you can use the even more lightweight `DataGroup` (though I'm not exactly sure how that behaves on mobile).

Comment: I learnt flex all by myself.I thought I'm qualified enough to write an app but it appears now that I've got a lot to improve.however,thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can I achieve this with less memory usage?
```

Yes!  With your current approach; if you have 60 instances of your component, then the app creates 60 instances of the component, renders them all and puts them on the screen; even if they are not currently a view area.

You should make use of a class, such as a List or DataGroup, as @RiaStar suggests.  Your custom component, PlayerInfo, should be used as the itemRenderer and the 'list' you are creating these components from should become the List's dataProvider.

Once you do this, then your app will make use of the List's renderer recycling.  So, only the visual elements displayed on screen will be displayed to the user.  So, if you have 10 items shown on screen from your list of 60; the app will generate 50 less an items.  This will make better use of processing power and better use of device memory.

To change your class to a renderer, you will have to implement a dataChange() event handler so that the component updates whenever the list changes the data that the renderer should display.

I don't think we enough information to get a more detailed explanation.  What is your dataProvider? What propeties need to be set on your custom component?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Reboog :D, though I haven't had time to test this,but I think it will work, thank you again.